# What is the best way to handle Coreference Resolution in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, coreference-resolution

For example,

Context: I am Yash and he is Jay who is my close friend.
Generated Question: Who is Jay?
Generated Answer: my close friend.

But the Answer should be something like following:

- Yash's close friend.
- Jay is a cose friend of Yash.

I have tried out AllenNLP and other Standford-NLP solutions but didn't work out at all.

Comment: Coreference resolution is pretty hard, I'm not surprised that it doesn't work. If you're interested in studying the research, you could look [here](https://nlpprogress.com/english/coreference_resolution.html). I'm not sure you will get an answer here, maybe you could have better suggestions on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Erwan. I have looked at these papers but still have difficulty finding the best solution.

Comment: I don't know what is the context of this task for you, but as far as I know this problem is an active problem in research, it doesn't have any really good solution yet. You won't find a library which does this, because it doesn't exist yet.